# How to tell GitLab that LICENSE.md, not LICENSE, has the text of the license for an R package?

Tags: r, gitlab

For writing R packages, CRAN is [very clear](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Licensing) that the file `LICENSE` must **not** contain the text of the license for the package. For instance, if my package is licensed under the MIT license, then `DESCRIPTION` contains the line `License: MIT + file LICENSE` and the file `LICENSE` contains two lines:

```
YEAR: <year>
COPYRIGHT HOLDER: <name>
```

I can have a file called `LICENSE.txt` or `LICENSE.md` that has the full text of the license. However, GitLab automatically assumes the `LICENSE` is the text of the license, so it links the License button on the project page to `LICENSE` and ignores `LICENSE.md` or `LICENSE.txt`.

Is there any way to tell GitLab to ignore `LICENSE` and link `LICENSE.md` or `LICENSE.txt` to the License button on the main project page?

Answer (score 0):

Click the `Add License` button on your project page. Then just change the filename from *LICENSE* to *LICENSE.md* and create the file. Gitlab then will consider your LICENSE.md file as the license and the button links to this file.

[image: Rename license file]

Comment: When I do that, GitLab still links the button to the `LICENSE` file and not `LICENSE.md`. 

To be clear, I have both a `LICENSE` and `LICENSE.md` in the directory. `LICENSE` is required for building the R package, but it is not the license that should be displayed by GitLab.

Comment: I tested what I described above. It was working but I only had the `LICENSE.md`, no `LICENSE`. Having both may not work though. You might want to raise an [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues) for that.

Comment: Good suggestion. I created an issue. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14093